# What is happening in my Android app to cause it to lose data?

Tags: android, file, filesystems, commit

I have an android app.  I have a few users who have a recurring problem: When the app shuts down, every file the app saved is gone.  Every folder created is gone.  Everything is completely wiped back to square one.

I am carefully saving the game data during every transition and game event, so I am very confident that this is not a case of the user crashing out before the data can be written.  Somehow, the data that IS being written but then it's just not persisting after the app is removed from memory.

So-- has anyone had this situation and solved it?  The only thing I can imagine is that there's some kind of "filesystem.commit" command I need to call after writing the files, but I can't find that documented anywhere.

Please help!

(Edit) I'm using native code to read and write files.  The code I use to write a file is this:

```
bool WriteFile(char *theFilename, char *theDataPtr, int theLen)
{
    FILE* aFile=fopen(theFilename,"w+");
    if(!aFile) {Alert("unable to create file %s with error %d", theFilename, errno);return false;}

    if(aFile) fclose(aFile);
    aFile=fopen(theFilename,"w+b");
    if(!aFile) {Alert ("unable to open file %s", theFilename);return false;}
    if (aFile)
    {
        fwrite(theDataPtr, 1, theLen,aFile);
        fclose(aFile);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note:No customers are reporting any alert popups, which are just normal Android message boxes.  Also note that this code works on almost every other system-- there's just a few customers that get the wiped data, so I was wondering if it's some weird security or some extra step I need to do to be 100% compatible with all systems.

(Edit) One more piece of information... this is the Java code I use to get the storage path for the app... all files that I try to write are put in this folder.

```
private void SetFilePath() 
{
    String storagePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();

    // SDCARD
    try {
        String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(storageState))
            storagePath = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(IDS.LOG,
                "No permission to access external storage, missing android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    }

    SetFilePathNative(storagePath); // Tells the native code the path
    mStorageDir = storagePath;
}
```

Comment: Please put the code that you’re using to save your data so we can troubleshoot :)

Comment: Hi, I added the code.  It's probably not significant, it's just very vanilla C++ file writes (native code).